# Simple present exercise - Rohan and Sania - Is the subject considered plural?

Tags: subjects, present-tense

I'm doing a simple present tense exercise, but I've come across a problem.

Rohan and Sania_______(like) to play card games.

Being native speaker I know that 'like' sounds (and probably is) correct. However, when I was looking at the rules for simple present tense it says that if the subject is singular noun or pronoun then the verb ends in -s. Are Rohan and Sania considered singular nouns? If so, should 'like' not end in -s?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be

> Rohan and Sania **like** to play card games.

Compound subjects linked by *and* take the plural form of the verb. See this [link](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/) for your reference. Rules 1, 2 and 3 will be most helpful for compound subjects

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link! I've just started Rex Barks by Phyllis Davenport and she teaches you how to do sentence diagramming...excited!

Answer (score 1):

Here, the *compound subject* consists of **two** singular nouns, viz., "Rohan and Sania". Therefore, the verb should be in the III person plural (they) form, which is "like" and not "likes".

Comment: Both yours and the above answers were very well explained - thank you!

Comment: It's a pleasure!